# for each loop is not working in nodejs mongoose, shows error Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongoose

here i am running foreach loop, the error i am getting is Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
module.exports.landingPageTrove = function(req, res) {
              Trove.find({type: 'Trending', is_verified: true}, '_id title cover_image user_id').populate({path: 'user_id', select: 'profile_photo -_id'}).limit(4).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, trove) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.send(err);
                } 
                else {
                  var link = {
                    "trending": {
                      "troves":""
                    }
                  };
                  trove.forEach(function(t){
                    Link.find({trove_id:t._id}, '_id title url').exec(function(err, result) {
                      console.log(result);
                      var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t));
                      temp["links"] = result;
                      link['trending']["troves"] = temp;
                      res.status(200).send(link);
                    });
                  })
                }
              });
            };
```

the output which i am getting from this code is

[image]

But i want some thing like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happening because you call `res.status(200).send(link);` inside loop (4 times). So it finishing request after first call. Just put this command outside loop. To wait while all 4 secondary request will be finished (you need to wait 4 responses from DB) use **async** library: https://github.com/caolan/async.

You interested in async's series feature:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
]);
```

Comment: It can be done without that specific lib, but you will be forced to handle asyncronous requests by yourself. So `async` is a good option. But it would be better in your case use `async.map` instead of `series`